# Hide pop up programmatically in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net web application. Here I have used a div element for creating a pop up. I want to programmatically hide this pop up on click of the open button in IE. This open button is not on my webpage instead it is a button displayed by the IE browser(refer snapshot attached at :-https://www.dropbox.com/s/0f3enyilj70fno2/image001.png?dl=0).

I have highlighted both pop up and the open button in the snapshot for your reference. Please leave your suggestions.Let me know if you need additional info. Thanks

Code Snippet:-

```
$("#dialog-showAdditionalInformationItem").dialog({

    resizable: false,

    autoOpen: false,

    dialogClass: "no-close no-corner ui-corner-flat",

    height: 480,

    width: 500,

    modal: true

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not simple. The browser itself has no way to detect that. The only way is to use a server-side tool.

When the server detect the beginning of the download, it can "alert" the browser. So you can hide the dialog box. But a communication "server" => "browser" is only possible with websocket or Comet. You can also perform an "active waiting", but it's a terrible practice.